# About the parameters in corr.test when I use in RNAseq data

Tags: r, correlation

I have some questions about the corr.test() function when I use in bulk RNAseq data.

Now my code is:

```
tm <- corr.test(data_cor,
                y = data_cor, use = "pairwise", "spearman", adjust="none", 
                alpha=0.05, ci=F, minlength=5)
tm$r
tm$p
```

What confused me is if I should use these parameters above just like "spearman","pairwise"
or like this:method="pearson" is the default value. The alternatives to be passed to cor are "spearman" and "kendall"

Can you give me some adivce ?

Comment: Who can help me

Comment: Read the manual page for `corr.test`. `tm <- corr.test(data_cor, use = "pairwise", method="spearman", adjust="none", alpha=0.05, ci=F,  minlength=5)` should work fine. If not provide a sample of your data. If you are asking what method of correlation is recommended for bulk RNAseq data, you should post on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).